# How can use firestore using where and orderby in flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

How can use firestore using where and orderby in flutter?

When I wanna to use both, I got the error.

[image]

```
Exception has occurred.
_CastError (Null check operator used on a null value)
```

code

```
StreamBuilder(
        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('Posts')
            .where('country', isEqualTo: user.country)
            //.where('country', isEqualTo: 'Australia')
            .orderBy('time', descending: true)
            .snapshots(),
        builder: (context,
            AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return const Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          }
          //print(user.country);
          return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) => Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                  horizontal: width > webScreenSize ? width * 0.3 : 0,
                  vertical: width > webScreenSize ? 15 : 0),
              child: PostCard(
                snap: snapshot.data!.docs[index],
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
```

So, why I could not got the data? I'd got the user.value.

Comment: On Stack Overflow, please don't show pictures of text and code.  Copy the text into the question itself and format it so that it's [easy to read, copy, and search](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/807126).  You can edit the question to correct this using the edit link at the bottom.

Comment: @DougStevenson got it, I'd updated the context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're telling Flutter that `snapshot.data` is guaranteed to have a value, when in reality it doesn't here:

```
return ListView.builder(
  itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
```

I recommend reading the documentation for `StreamBuilder` again, as there are many more states than `snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting` that you need to handle.

For example, there could be an error, or there could be no data for another reason:

```
StreamBuilder(
  stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('Posts')
      .where('country', isEqualTo: user.country)
      .orderBy('time', descending: true)
      .snapshots(),
  builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
      return const Center(
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
      );
    }

    //  Handle error
    if (snapshot.hasError) {
      return const Center(
        child: Text(snapshot.error),
      );
    }

    //  Handle lack of data
    if (!snapshot.hasData) {
      return const Center(
        child: Text("Something when wrong - no data available"),
      );
    }

    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) => Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
            horizontal: width > webScreenSize ? width * 0.3 : 0,
            vertical: width > webScreenSize ? 15 : 0),
        child: PostCard(
          snap: snapshot.data!.docs[index],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Comment: I don't know why... it's show me white screen...but not get error, just show white screen

Comment: When I add `if (snapshot.hasData) {
            print("ok");
          }` it's working and get print ok, but where has problem? Beause it's show white screen. When I move `ListView.builder` into `if (snapshot.hasData) {` I got error `FlutterError (setState() called after dispose(): _PostCardState#38f8a(lifecycle state: defunct, not mounted)
This error happens if you call setState() on a State object for a widget that no longer appears in the widget tree (e.g., whose parent widget no longer includes the widget in its build). `

Comment: None of the code in your question nor the change in my answer should be causing that error. If by applying the code I explained in my answer you were able to get past your original error, then it seems that this solves that problem. If you have another problem after that, I recommend posting it as a new question with its own [minimal repro](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).